# applying word2vec on small text files

Tags: nlp, text-mining, word2vec

I'm totally new to word2vec so please bear it with me. I have a set of text files each containing a set of tweets, between 1000-3000. I have chosen a common keyword (`"kw1"`) and I want to find semantically relevant terms for `"kw1"` using word2vec. For example if the keyword is `"apple"` I would expect to see related terms such as `"ipad" "os" "mac"`... based on the input file. So this set of related terms for `"kw1"` would be different for each input file as word2vec would be trained on individual files (eg., 5 input files, run word2vec 5 times on each file).

My goal is to find sets of related terms for each input file given the common keyword (`"kw1"`), which would be used for some other purposes.

My questions/doubts are:

- Does it make sense to use word2vec for a task like this? is it technically right to use considering the small size of an input file?

I have downloaded the code from code.google.com: https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ and have just given it a dry run as follows:

```
 time ./word2vec -train $file -output vectors.bin -cbow 1 -size 200 -window 10 -negative 25 -hs 1 -sample 1e-3 -threads 12 -binary 1 -iter 50

./distance vectors.bin
```

- From my results I saw I'm getting many noisy terms (stopwords) when I'm using the `'distance'` tool to get related terms to `"kw1"`. So I did remove stopwords and other noisy terms such as user mentions. But I haven't seen anywhere that word2vec requires cleaned input data?
- How do you choose right parameters? I see the results (from running the `distance` tool) varies greatly when I change parameters such as `'-window'`, `'-iter'`. Which technique should I use to find the correct values for the parameters. (manual trial and error is not possible for me as I'll be scaling up the dataset).

Comment: Interesting but not exactly the right stackexchange to ask these questions. I suggest asking the question on datascience.stackexchange.com or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gensim

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs to [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) SO Forum.

Comment: @sophros tags used are still active at SO so I suppose it still belongs here

Comment: @samsamara: it is not about the tags but about the nature of the question - which is rather generic and not related only to the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

First Question:

Yes, for almost any task that I can imagine word2vec being applied to you are going to have to clean the data - especially if you are interested in semantics (not syntax) which is the usual reason to run word2vec. Also, it is not just about removing stopwords although that is a good first step. Typically you are going to want to have a tokenizer and sentence segmenter as well, I think if you look at the document for deeplearning4java (which has a word2vec implementation) it shows using these tools. This is important since you probably don't care about the relationship between apple and the number "5", apple and "'s", etc...
For more discussion on preprocessing for word2vec see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/word2vec-toolkit/TI-TQC-b53w

Second Question:

There is no automatic tuning available for word2vec AFAIK, since that implys the author of the implementation knows what you plan to do with it. Typically default values for the implementation are the "best" values for whoever implemented on a (or a set of) tasks. Sorry, word2vec isn't a turn-key solution. You will need to understand the parameters and adjust them to fix your task accordingly.

Comment: but i haven't seen anywhere mentioning about removing stopwords? Doesn't the word2vec is supposed to handle stop words even if you don't remove them?

Comment: By word2vec do you mean the algorithm or the implementation you cite above? I read Tomas's 2013 paper and there is no mention of stopwords, this is an implementation detail, the algorithm doesn't require it. Also, I would be surprised if they word2vec implementation you mention from google groups removes them, since there is no agreed set of stop words. Some linguistics doing specialized tasks may even want traditional stop words included, although I think this would be rare in English. Does that help?